# Django return none when y try to save in vars by POST method

Tags: python, django, post, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to save the data from a form by POST method. When i try to save in vars at views.py it put inside none

here i show important parts of my code:

add.html:

```
<form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <h5>AÑADIR PEDIDO</h5>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cliente">Nombre del Cliente</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cliente" placeholder="pepito" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="producto">Codigo del Producto</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="producto">
          {% for cantidades in cantidad_pedido %}
          <option value="{{cantidades.Cproducto}}">
            {{cantidades.Cproducto}}
          </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de dicho producto</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad" placeholder="cantidad" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Añadir!</button>
    </form>
```

models.py:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
Cproducto = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
cantidad = models.IntegerField()

class Pedido(models.Model):
Cpedido = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
Ccliente = models.CharField(max_length=50)
FechaPedido = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

class detallePedido(models.Model):
Cpedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Cproducto = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Cantidad = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py :

```
def add(request):
cantidad_pedido = Stock.objects.all()
if request.POST:
    client = request.POST.get('cliente')
    producto = request.POST.get('producto')
    cantidad = request.POST.get('cantidad')
    stock_producto = Stock.objects.get(Cproducto=producto)

    if(cantidad > stock_producto.cantidad):
        messages.error(request, 'Error, la cantidad es mayor')

return render(request, 'add.html', {'cantidad_pedido': cantidad_pedido})
```

and here one picture of the vars:

[image]

Comment: You are missing name attribute on all of your input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing as mention above in comment
I think you are making request with id attribute but instead of id you need to do with name attribute like this

```
form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <h5>AÑADIR PEDIDO</h5>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cliente">Nombre del Cliente</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cliente" placeholder="pepito" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="producto">Codigo del Producto</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="producto">
          {% for cantidades in cantidad_pedido %}
          <option value="{{cantidades.Cproducto}}">
            {{cantidades.Cproducto}}
          </option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cantidad">Cantidad de dicho producto</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad" placeholder="cantidad" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Añadir!</button>
    </form>
```

and you can use both id and name but for making request you need to name attribute